# CO2 probe measuring at temperatures up to 150 °C

Tags: airflow, gas

I'm looking for a $CO_2$ measuring probe (analog current output, digital out: RS232/485 - probe will be connected and transferring real time data to the data logger) that would operate up to 150 °C (hot air sucked out from the heated column which is highly concentrated by $CO_2$). The probe will not measure $CO_2$ concentration continually but in cycles - every 20 or 30 minutes, the probe should operate for about 1 or 2 minutes.

Another $CO_2$ probe should measure (rather control) trace amount of $CO_2$ after it's separated from the exhaust gas (small scale experimental boiler burning coal) - operating temp. approx. 75 °C. This probe is expected to measure $CO_2$ concentration rather continually or at least in cycles being 60+ minutes long.

I have found tons of probes, but all of them can operate up to + 60/70 °C. Some of them can withstand high temperatures while not measuring $CO_2$.

Do you have any experiences with such probes?

Comment: Consider cooling a gas stream separated from the main flow

Comment: This sensor claims to be able to withstand the temperature range you're in.https://gaslab.com/collections/co2/products/ir-incubator-co2-sensor

Comment: @SolarMike I did, but it would mean installing an addition heat exchanger. I expect using just a cool air blower won't help. The problem is with the stream, which can't be concentrated, because it flows into a cryogenic unit where the highest CO2 concentration is needed due to its efficiency and energy requirements to achieve the low temperature.

Comment: @J.Ari Thanks, but I have found such sensors used for incubation. According to the data sheet, 190°C is just a max, temperature the sensor can withstand. However, operational conditions for CO2 measuring is 0 - 60°C.

Comment: @Josh E. You are probably best off talking with a vendor directly about your application.